# Migrate from XML-RPC to REST

Tags: xml-rpc, infusionsoft, xmlrpcclient

I'm using JAVA and I must convert every single XML-RPC call to a REST one.
How do I do it?

I'm using KEAP (previously known as "Infusionsoft") as CRM.
I have a lot of calls like this one:

`Object[] objects=(Object[]) crmClient.execute("DataService.findByField", parameters);`

What is the precise migrations process I have to follow?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you're up and running and able to make REST calls (authorized, access token management, and able to successful make call) you'll need to reference the documentation for the xml api https://developer.keap.com/docs/xml-rpc/ and the rest api https://developer.keap.com/docs/rest/#!/ and try to find the call the matches.

For your findByField example the xml api link
https://developer.keap.com/docs/xml-rpc/#data-retrieve-a-record
matches with this call in the REST api
https://developer.keap.com/docs/rest/#!/Contact/getContactUsingGET.

The way the data is returned will most likely be a different format so you'll need to make sure whatever code happens next can access the data that is returned.

Then repeat for all the other calls. Not every xml call with have a 100% match in rest so you might have to get creative if you run into any hurdles.